# How to add 9 months and 7 days to a date "27-05-2018" in python

Tags: python

How to add 9 months and 7 days to a date "27-05-2018" in python
below is my code attempt which only adds days but how to add months.?

```
import datetime
d=datetime.date(2018,5,27)
dd=datetime.timedelta(days=7)
print(d+dd)
```

Comment: ohh, what is that code about, short lengthen question

Comment: This question is under-specified. What for example, would be 9-months + 7-days from 2018-05-31? 9 months after this date would be "31st February" - which doesn't exist.

Comment: The problem here is the definition of "month." Each month of the calendar year has differing lengths (one of which depends on the year!).

Comment: @jpp Oh maan, you're right, also edited mine for this, there are 31 days and 30 days, i deleted my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use relativedelta instead of timedelta.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
d=datetime.date(2018,5,27)
date_delta=relativedelta(months=+9, days=+7)
print(d+date_delta)
```

Output:

```
2019-03-06
```